# clear the archive bit in windows

Tags: java, windows

I am trying to clear the archive bit in some files in windows 7 64bit. I have tried the code:

```
atrrib -a * /s
```

The error I get: 'atrrib' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

I am having a small java code going through the file. If there is a way to do it in java would be preferable.

Comment: try attrib not atrrib

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Java7 you can do this:

```
File theFile = new File("c:/foobar.txt");
Path file = theFile.toPath();
Files.setAttribute(file, "dos:archive", false);
```

Answer (score 2):

Too many r's, try this:

```
attrib -a * /s
```

Answer (score 0):

Run with the full path.
C:>%SystemRoot%\system32\attrib

There is an issue with the environment variable path and the use of attrib.

See this link for more detail.
http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/63b84992-3814-4c00-acbf-fc09816570e5/problem-in-path-settings-windows7?forum=w7itprogeneral