# Is there a way to default or suggest a folder structure on a direct download without using a zip file?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, download, jszip

### Q: Is there a way to default or suggest a folder structure on a direct download without using a zip file?

I have an AngularJS app that I use to generate text files that are imported into a commercial machine. In order for the import to work, the file has to be embedded in a particular folder structure. Is there a way to suggest this folder structure via the download dialog without having to use a zip file?

We use a zip today, but Windows users are having problems with the extracts working on the machine (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51314977/631272)). Curious if there was a way to bypass the zip altogether.

Relevant info:

- Angular version: 5.2.10
- Zip Utility in angular: JSZip 3.1.5

JSZip code:

```
const zip = new JSZip();
zip.folder('FolderA/FolderB/FolderC').file('FILE.TXT', new File([contentString], 'TEMP.TXT', { type: 'text/plain' }));
zip.generateAsync({ type: 'blob' })
  .then(function (content) {
    saveAs(content, 'ZipFile.ZIP');
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use tar instead of zip.

https://github.com/beatgammit/tar-js

But no, you you can't download a directory unless it's somehow converted to a single file.

Comment: tar won't work for my purposes, but I'm accepting for confirming that it isn't possible. Thanks for your answer!